# Redux source directory structuring in Javascript

Tags: redux, directory-structure

I am exploring a simple redux counter example (using plain npm Javascript standalone project).

Thinking in terms of better code maintenance in medium and large applications , I looking to find-out pros and cons b/w below two styles

1. Style-1 : Creating common folders at top level dirs like below :-

   some-react-proj :

   ```
   src/ :
      store/:           
         actions/: 
              counterActions.js
              messageActions.js
              index.js
         actionCreators/: 
              counterActionCreator.js
              messageActionCreator.js
              index.js
         reducers/:
              counterReducer.js
              messageReducer.js
              index.js
   ```
2. Style-2 : Separating folders by functionality, like :-

   some-react-proj :

   ```
   src/ :
      store/:           
         counter/: 
              counterActions.js
              counterActionCreator.js
              counterReducer.js
              index.js
         message/: 
              messageReducer.js
              messageActions.js
              messageActionCreator.js
              index.js
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one is closer to the current recommendations, but the current recommendations go even further and have you place all of that in one file, and that file next to related components.

The official recommendation is to place reducer, selectors and action creators that belong together into one "feature slice" file, next to components files for that feature into a "feature folder": [Redux Style Guide: Structure Files as Feature Folders with Single-File Logic](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide/#structure-files-as-feature-folders-with-single-file-logic)

Obviously sometimes you will have actions that might not really only belong to ONE reducer or feature - you can place those with the feature that belongs to them "the most", or just keep them separated as you want.

For an example of that file structure, you can also look at the file structures provided by the official Redux "Create React App" templates by calling
`npx create-react-app my-app --template redux` or `npx create-react-app my-app --template redux-typescript`

Also, this approach goes well with the [`createSlice` function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) provided by the official redux toolkit that (among other things, like removing the need to write immutable updates by hand) automatically creates action creators for you for "case reducers" you declare and makes stuff like action string types obsolete.

Generally I can highly recommend you to look into [modern redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) and maybe go through the official [Redux "essentials" tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) that shows how to use modern Redux in practice.